# Shutting down namenode hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to setup a hadoop cluster and get this following error:-

```
 $HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hdfs namenode -format 

Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory /var/hadoop/hadoop-namenode ? (Y or N) Y
17/09/11 19:41:55 INFO namenode.FSImage: Allocated new BlockPoolId: BP-448039548-10.211.55.101-1505158915421
17/09/11 19:41:55 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /var/hadoop/hadoop-namenode has been successfully formatted.
17/09/11 19:41:55 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 1 images with txid >= 0
17/09/11 19:41:55 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
17/09/11 19:41:55 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at node1/10.211.55.101
```

Im trying to follow this tutorial to setup the cluster.

https://github.com/vangj/vagrant-hadoop-2.4.1-spark-1.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an error.  Before you can start HDFS, you need to format the namenode.  This is similar to before you can run Linux/Windows you need to format the disk.